# Is it possible to toggle between disabling and enabling a DT table?

Tags: r, shiny, dt, shinyjs

I have an app which has a DT table with row selection enabled.  Is it possible to toggle between disabling and enabling the entire table without rerendering it?  Using `shinyjs::disable` and `shinyjs::enable` will disable and enable the text boxes in the table used for filtering, but not the ability to select rows.  I'm also not aware of any DT proxy method that would accomplish what I'm trying to do.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  DTOutput("table"),
  actionButton(inputId = "disable",
               label = "Disable"),
  actionButton(inputId = "enable",
               label = "Enable"),
  useShinyjs()
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$table <- renderDT({
    data <- data.frame(COL_1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                       COL_2 = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    datatable(data,
              escape = FALSE,
              filter = list(position = "top"),
              rownames = FALSE)
  })


  observeEvent(input$disable, {
    disable(id = "table")
  })

  observeEvent(input$enable, {
    enable(id = "table")
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that I could accomplish this by using `event.stopPropagation()` within the `tbody` element of the datatable.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  DTOutput("table"),
  actionButton(inputId = "disable",
               label = "Disable"),
  actionButton(inputId = "enable",
               label = "Enable"),
  useShinyjs()
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$table <- renderDT({
    data <- data.frame(COL_1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                       COL_2 = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    datatable(data,
              escape = FALSE,
              filter = list(position = "top"),
              rownames = FALSE)
  })


  observeEvent(input$disable, {
    runjs("document.getElementById('table').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].setAttribute('onmousedown', 'event.stopPropagation();');")
  })

  observeEvent(input$enable, {
    runjs("document.getElementById('table').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].removeAttribute('onmousedown');")
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no [proxy method](https://rdrr.io/cran/DT/man/proxy.html) fitting your needs, accordingly  you'll have to re-render your table.

However, you don't need `library(shinyjs)`.

Please check the following:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  DTOutput("table"),
  actionButton(inputId = "disable",
               label = "Disable"),
  actionButton(inputId = "enable",
               label = "Enable")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  dtSettings <- reactiveValues(searchable = TRUE, mode = "multiple")

  output$table <- renderDT({
    data <- data.frame(COL_1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                       COL_2 = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    datatable(data,
              escape = FALSE,
              filter = list(position = "top"),
              rownames = FALSE,
              selection = list(mode = dtSettings$mode , selected = NULL, target = 'row'),
              options = list(
                columnDefs = list(list(targets = seq_len(ncol(data))-1, searchable = dtSettings$searchable)),
                pageLength = 5
              ))
  }, server = FALSE)

  observeEvent(input$disable, {
    dtSettings$searchable <- FALSE
    dtSettings$mode <- "none"
  })

  observeEvent(input$enable, {
    dtSettings$searchable <- TRUE
    dtSettings$mode <- "multiple"
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks for posting a solution.  For my particular workflow, I can't rerender the table.  However, I ended up figuring out how to do it using javascript.  See my posted solution.